# What does 'finish in' mean in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, function, closures

I'm a noob and have been learning from Apple's Playgrounds and random books doing tutorials.  I'm working on a tutorial where it deals with a closure.  I've seen this 'finish in' before in another tutorial but I don't know what it means precisely in layman terms.

What is it finishing, what is being finished, and inside of what?  Or is there an idea of order of operation?

Here is the function where it was used:

```
func playSequence(index: Int, highlightTime: Double){
        currentPlayer = .Computer

        if index == inputs.count{
            currentPlayer = .Human
            return
        }

        var button: UIButton = buttonByColor(color: inputs[index])
        var originalColor: UIColor? = button.backgroundColor
        var highlightColor: UIColor = UIColor.white

        UIView.animate(withDuration: highlightTime, delay: 0.0, options: [.curveLinear, .allowUserInteraction, .beginFromCurrentState], animations: {
            button.backgroundColor = highlightColor
        }, completion: {
            finished in button.backgroundColor = originalColor
            var newIndex: Int = index + 1
            self.playSequence(index: newIndex, highlightTime: highlightTime)
        })
    }
```

Comment: Everything's sequential from top to bottom. The last part is an animation...the button backgroundColor is set to the highlight color. When the animation completes (the duration is the `highlightTime` parameter of the method), the code in the completion block executes.

Comment: @Adrian The question is specifically about the `finished in` part, not a general question about the `UIView animate...` method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`finished` is the parameter to the `completion` closure. The `in` is simply part of Swift's closure syntax.

The full signature of the `UIView animate` method is:

> class func animate(withDuration duration: TimeInterval, delay: TimeInterval, options: UIViewAnimationOptions = [], animations: @escaping () -> Void, completion: ((Bool) -> Void)? = nil)

Note the `Bool` parameter to the `completion` closure. The `finished` in your code is the name given to that parameter.

An excerpt from the documentation about the `completion` parameter states:

> This block has no return value and takes a single Boolean argument that indicates whether or not the animations actually finished before the completion handler was called.

A more typical way to write the code is as:

```
UIView.animate(withDuration: highlightTime, delay: 0.0, options: [.curveLinear, .allowUserInteraction, .beginFromCurrentState], animations: { 
    // animation code
}) { (finished) in
    // completion code
}
```

This syntax makes it clearer than the syntax you are using. This is also using the "trailing closure" syntax.

Another way, closer to your usage, would be:

```
UIView.animate(withDuration: highlightTime, delay: 0.0, options: [.curveLinear, .allowUserInteraction, .beginFromCurrentState], animations: { 
    // animation code
}, completion: { (finished) in
    // completion code
})
```

Your usage simply omits the parentheses around the parameter and it leaves out a line break. Adding those back in makes the code clearer.

Comment: Thank you this helps as well.  What should I search for if I want to understand what the word 'in' does or is this just the parameter name?

Comment: Please read the [Closures](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Closures.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH11-ID94) chapter of the [The Swift Programming Language](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH3-ID0) book. `in` is just part of the syntax.